# Keep maximum value per group including repetitions

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
    a   b   c
0   x1  y1  9
1   x1  y2  9
2   x1  y3  4
3   x2  y4  2
4   x2  y5  10
5   x2  y6  5
6   x3  y7  6
7   x3  y8  4
8   x3  y9  8
9   x4  y10 11
10  x4  y11 11
11  x4  y12 11
```

I first want to do a grouped sort of column `c` (grouped by column `a`), and then I want to retain all the rows in each group that have the highest values of column `c`. So the output will look like:

```
    a   b   c
0   x1  y1  9
1   x1  y2  9
4   x2  y5  10
8   x3  y9  8
9   x4  y10 11
10  x4  y11 11
11  x4  y12 11
```

Is there a clean way of doing so without using any loops, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) column `a` and find the [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) per group, and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) back the resulting dataframe to keep the matching rows:

```
df.merge(df.groupby('a').c.max())

    a    b   c
0  x1   y1   9
1  x1   y2   9
2  x2   y5  10
3  x3   y9   8
4  x4  y10  11
5  x4  y11  11
6  x4  y12  11
```

Comment: Nice and short.. +1.

Comment: This is really short syntax but @Ben.T solution is better timing wise.   This joining to dataframe vs boolean selecting he original dataframe after groupby calculation. +1 also.

Comment: Yep, indeed a simple boolean indexing will be faster than a join. Though for not too large dataframes the difference should't be much of a problem, and guess this approach is nice to have for conciseness @ScottBoston

Answer (score 4):

you can do it with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) with `max` like:

```
df.loc[df['c'].eq(df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('max')), :]
     a    b   c
0   x1   y1   9
1   x1   y2   9
4   x2   y5  10
8   x3   y9   8
9   x4  y10  11
10  x4  y11  11
11  x4  y12  11
```

Comment: `df[df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('max') == df['c']]`  Much short syntax but yours is very readable. +1

Comment: @ScottBoston so I always use `loc` in my codes to ensure that it is a copy (when needed) and prevent the well known `settingwithcopywarning` for something later on and avoid spending time to find where it is from. But you are right in this case it is not necessary and your syntax is cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `groupby` and `sort_values`

```
df = df.groupby(['a'])['c'].sum().reset_index()
df = df.sort_values(by=['c'], ascending=False)
```